# Which EntitySetRights Enumeration should I use

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I have the following requirements:

- users should not be able to insert or delete from Orders entities
- users are able to update or replace Orders entities

Which code is better for it:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule ("Orders", EntitySetRights.WriteMerge | 
EntitySetRights.WriteReplace);
```

or:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule ("Orders",  EntitySetRights.AllWrite);
```

And what is the difference between:
EntitySetRights.AllWrite 
EntitySetRights.All       ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this documentation sumarizes it pretty well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.entitysetrights.aspx
WriteMerge allows MERGE operations. WriteReplace allows PUT operations. AllWrite allows POST/PUT/MERGE/DELETE but doesn't allow any GET.
All allows everything.
Looking it your requirements you need at least AllWrite, if you also want to allow querying you would need to add either ReadSingle or ReadMultiple or both (in which case All is easier).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, slowly I get the point, but users should not able to insert or delete from Orders entities, so AllWrite is not the best choice, or am I wrong here (I'm a newbie)???

Comment: Sorry - I misread your question. You need just WriteReplace and WriteMerge.